# SSD1306 as a framebuffer with fbtft driver on a raspberry pi 2

Tags: linux, framebuffer

I am facing an issue when trying to use my oled screen as a standard and simple linux framebuffer.
I followed these instructions for the wiring 
https://learn.adafruit.com/ssd1306-oled-displays-with-raspberry-pi-and-beaglebone-black/wiring

And try to load the driver with

```
modprobe fbtft_device name=adafruit13m debug=1 gpios=reset:24,dc:23
```

The driver seems to load correctly.

However, I can't get to show an image on it with fbi:

```
fbi -d /dev/fb1  -a happycat_oled_64.ppm 

using "DejaVu Sans Mono-16", pixelsize=16,67 file=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
ioctl VT_GETSTATE: Ioctl() inappropré pour un périphérique (not a linux console?)
```

I found a discussion on github about a problem that may be related:
https://github.com/notro/fbtft/issues/169

Has someone managed to get this little screen working as a framebuffer, and would share some details?
Do you know another way to test the framebuffer?

As a side note, the adafruit tutorial provides several python examples that uses a userspace driver, and I managed to show an image using them.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know another way to test the framebuffer?

the command "dmesg" gives out all loaded modules, if you loaded a module correctly then it should appear at the end of a gigantic output of modules.

[roughly the last 10 lines are description of the module]

> fbi -d /dev/fb1  -a happycat_oled_64.ppm
>
> using "DejaVu Sans Mono-16", pixelsize=16,67 file=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
>
> > ioctl VT_GETSTATE: Ioctl() inappropré pour un périphérique (not a linux console?)

I'm not sure what this means, but my little bit of french allows me to translate the following:
"Input-Output-Controll stopped the application due to inappropriate input for this device."
Check your arguments, that might help.