# Raspberry boot splash image on oled by SPI

Tags: boot, display

Lets say i have a raspberry pi attached to a spi oled screen.
life is good , i can display nice text and graphics after boot...

But , i wonder , is possible to display an splash image during boot?
or display the console output during boot ??

[image]https://www.adafruit.com/products/938

Comment: I have an RPi attached to an SPI LCD screen, and it starts displaying console text somewhere in the middle of the boot process; probably as soon as the driver is initialized. Do you have a Linux driver for the display? Do you think console output at 128x64 pixels would be useful?

Comment: I doubt this works as a normal display like the LCDs do, would be part of the issue here.    It is unlikely to receive an answer without further information about the way the screen behaves and is used.

Comment: @JimmyB My apologies!  Missed that.

Comment: Apparently, my other comment was deleted when the question was migrated. I suggested to search for "framebuffer" in conjunction with SSD1306, which I assume is the driver chip of the display. See e.g. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28813/ssd1306-as-a-framebuffer-with-fbtft-driver-on-a-raspberry-pi-2.

Comment: That thing doesn't *necessarily* have any (display related) kernel driver at all, which is why I've said more information is needed (I won't actually close the question now because there is no point in bouncing the migration).  It *could* be entirely controlled with userland software, the only kernel level stuff is the generic SPI interface.

Comment: See also https://hallard.me/adafruit-ssd1306-oled-display-driver-for-raspberry-pi/

Comment: @goldilocks The display is connected via *SPI*, not *I²C*. And yes, it is normally controlled from userland via SPI. But that doesn't mean that there is no display driver for the SSD1306 (or SH1106), which is what the OP needs and which we could help him find.

Comment: @JimmyB Whoops again -- but it amounts to the same thing in context, which I think you know.  I agree there could be a kernel driver used, my point was there isn't *necessarily* one.  If there is one available *and it's a display driver that fulfills certain prerequisites, which again isn't necessarily the case* it is a reasonable suggestion (I did not delete the initial comment, BTW).

Comment: Anyway, my point here is not aimed at you, it's aimed at the OP.  Unless someone comes by who has that device and has done this, likely no one is going to bother writing an answer without more information *in the question.*  But if I close it as unclear it gets bounced, which means any opportunity to edit it is gone.